# How to print rows using ORDER BY in FastReport?

Tags: sql, delphi, fastreport

I have a Delphi application with Salary table, I created an SQL query to sort Salaries from up to down by using `ORDER BY Salary DESC`, the operation success in DBGrid but in FastReport failed and didn't sort anything.
Take a look at the pictures for more info.

[image]

In FastReport the result is not like I want

[image]

Comment: Well, use the same data source as your grid.

Comment: You don't sort in FR. You sort the data it is connected to instead. FR's DataSet is only used to connect the data to the report's controls and to control looping.

Comment: How you show the report? did you clear the last prepared one?

Comment: Thanks Victoria, when i connect the same DataSource it work well !

Comment: You're welcome! Well, so long this was a mistake, I would suggest you deleting this question ;-)